# Angular 2 app deployed and throws a 404 when I go to mydomain.com/search

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular, http-status-code-404

I have some routes defined.  Here's a snippet:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchComponent
  }
]
```

My app has been deployed now, but I am not able to go to a direct route such as `mydomain.com/search` because I am treated with a 404.  However, I can go to `mydomain.com/` and click a link to `/search` from the home page.  That works just fine.

I am using apache.  How can I resolve this 404 issue so that I can go to `mydomain.com/search` and have it work by showing me the search page?

I know there is a way to do this using hash location strategy, but I am interested to know the way to do it on the apache server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to .htaccess file or httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L] 
</IfModule>
```

need to add AllowOverride option to Directory in httpd.conf

here /var/www/html is the root of my project

add .htaccess file to your project

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: thanks Eswar.  Where do I update the AllowOverride option?  There are a couple of them in httpd

Comment: also do i do AllowOverride all, or ?  sorry i am new to this.  thank you

Comment: While that approach is your answer, let me explain your issue and how that answer fixes it. Your issue is that whenever you try to go directly to the /search URL, the web server tries to find a file or a directory with that name, but that is not an actual file or directory, but an Angular 2 route, so you get a 404 error (not found). So the solution is to make your web server (if you are using Apache, you would edit its configuration, that's what that answer is for, Apache) and tell it to re-write all requests to that directory to the index of the Angular 2 application (index.html).